# pandas plotting a group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to plot the following data which is a count of unique text

```
Element              
Motor 1  thermiek        15
         tijd te lang     9
Motor 2  thermiek        12
         tijd te lang     3
Motor 3  thermiek         5
         tijd te lang     4
dtype: int64

by_element = data.groupby('Element')
by_element['Alarm tekst'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

result of code

[image]

How can I make the plot be grouped like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work to get a grouped bar chart similar to the one linked in your comment:

```
gb = df.groupby(['Element','Alarm tekst'])
gb['Alarm tekst'].count().unstack().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Original suggestion for aggregated bar:

You should include the `agg()` function to count the total values.

```
data.groupby('Element').agg('count').plot(kind = 'bar')
```

If your second column is already summed by term you can use `agg(numpy.sum)` instead:

```
import numpy    
data.groupby('Element').agg(numpy.sum).plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: i do not want them to be added up i want something like http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/_images/bar_plot_multi_ex.png